# How to get count of nodes in firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can i know the below code is correct to receive the count of nodes in firebase database by status?

```
// Add Auth State Changed event listener
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        self.user = user;
        db.child('referrals').orderByChild("uid").equalTo(user.uid).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.val().status == 0)
                self.submitted++;
            else if (snapshot.val().status == 1)
                self.pending++;
            else if (snapshot.val().status == 2)
                self.approved++;
        });
    } else {
        console.log('not logged in');
        $location.path('').replace();
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want to get the number of children of a snapshot, you can just use `snapshot.numChildren()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/26497677.